The value which have decimal numbers are getting changed while displaying in the page
The query will give the value for **startvalue **is 4920.25
but when i tried to displat that value in page the value displays as 4954.72
    <CFQUERY name="get" DATASOURCE="HeliosMaster">
        exec DB01.Logging.Benchmarking_History
    </CFQUERY>

<cfoutput query="get">
<TR class="tableItems">
<TD>#NumberFormat(SinceStart)#</TD>
</TR>
</cfoutput>

Tried using Numberformat(), DecimalFormat()
The page should display exactly what it is there in Query Result.

Try sharing some of your code.

@TRose Updated the Question description, Added the code

Is this query from a CFM, part of a function call in a CFC? Are you sure the stored procedure is being called in a thread-safe manner? How is the variable SinceStart being defined? You mention a variable startvalue, but where is that in your code? I feel there's a lot of code being left out here. If you run that stored procedure on the database, outside of your CF app, does it return the correct value?

What happens when you dump the data? Does your query return two (2) columns with the same "SinceStart" name? (I've encountered this issue before when consuming third-party spreadsheet files as query data.)
